# Certificate not work when i try to update

Tags: google-app-engine

Good day to all. I am using Google App Engine 1.6.2 , Python 2.7 ,Windows 7x64, i created an application..uploded it...it was successfully working for about a weak. But when i was trying to make an update this morning, luncher gave me this error:

```
2012-02-20 12:26:41 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=myemail@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'D:\\Dropbox\\Google\\handmade']"
Application: bubonchikhub; version: 1
Host: appengine.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 101, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 97, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3935, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3926, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2497, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3692, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2915, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2897, in UpdateVersion
    updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 572, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=self.config.runtime)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 365, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1207, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 363, in do_open
    url_error.reason.args[1])
fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host 127.0.0.1:8888 returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed): 
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl
2012-02-20 12:26:43 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.


You can close this window now.
```

Can anyone help how to fix this?
Thnx in advance

Comment: Try again, it happens once and a while. looks like an issue with the app engine itself.

Comment: A solution that worked for me is deleting gae certificates cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/14004826/5181

Answer (score 2):

Your request might be going through a local proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Python 2.7.9 fixed this for me.

Comment: I had Python 2.7.9, but upgrading to 2.7.13 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste your proxy's certification to the end of `google_appengine/lib/cacerts/cacerts.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be related to proxy servers, when I run fiddler and try to deploy I get this error. When I shut it down deployment works fine.

You will get an invalid certificate error like 
fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host 127.0.0.1:8888 returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed):

So turn of the proxy server (assuming this is your issue) you are running and and the run the appcfg deploy!