# Install chrome native client (nacl)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to install Chrome native client.

I went to this https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/download page to download and install the sdk. I followed the instructions in this page however when I tried to execute the `naclsdk list` command or any `naclsdk` command I got an error:

```
third_party.fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host storage.googleapis.com returned an invalid certificate ([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)):
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl
Usage: sdk_update_main.py <command> [options]
```

What is the problem here? Is there a problem with a certificate?

Comment: Check the solution provided in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/sh-9sA6LHjw). I think you need to edit the file "nacl_sdk/sdk_tools/sdk_update_main.py" and change the function `UrlOpen(url)` specified in the post. Also you may be interested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359745/certificate-not-work-when-i-try-to-update).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just comment two lines of sdk_tools/download.py

```
# ca_certs = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'cacerts.txt')

# request.set_ssl_info(ca_certs=ca_certs)
```

Answer (score 3):

When I tried applying the accepted answer, `download.py` was overwritten with the old version before it was executed.

Instead, I updated the certificates by replacing the contents of `cacerts.txt` with the certificate chain `storage.googleapis.com` is using today:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGcjCCBVqgAwIBAgIQBdcOj75NzEPW3Y45nh0r+zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBU
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEeMBwGA1UEChMVR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNlcnZpY2VzMSUw
IwYDVQQDExxHb29nbGUgSW50ZXJuZXQgQXV0aG9yaXR5IEczMB4XDTE5MDMwMTA5
MzY0NVoXDTE5MDUyNDA5MjUwMFowcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCkNh
bGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxEzARBgNVBAoMCkdvb2ds
ZSBMTEMxITAfBgNVBAMMGCouc3RvcmFnZS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJ
KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMhmw+ZB0GgoEEHQR+g75gfFMoqoBHvc
NADV8RJ5iCIiIQh2slRYv9Wai9/ZeYrxaJowLyEpi5n3ZjeIBBGitSnTd+sUOnT5
n/D/d5FCRKBcNkAJkdMtqnHJNPRt5xlheKlPYPzb+qR/BdoedfMbcgJ8Qgfg5mAb
xVpLOUGIKDNfC+z+wthXJJtqp2WU3MCKfFQy9tXodq043Mvdl0hEF4P3I3SSZioO
WK44JonwPbbvy7qk9ohrchfLa0VfPVN9rlpV0eoNTWISlNrK+fmBgj5lr7YNtfUK
lyi26L119hWPAlVpnHohf15iRPUudK70GY+xPbol6tD92pXY3pxPwD8CAwEAAaOC
AyAwggMcMBMGA1UdJQQMMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMBMIIB9QYDVR0RBIIB7DCCAeiCGCou
c3RvcmFnZS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbYIkKi5hcHBzcG90LmNvbS5zdG9yYWdlLmdv
b2dsZWFwaXMuY29tgiIqLmNvbW1vbmRhdGFzdG9yYWdlLmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29t
gikqLmNvbnRlbnQtc3RvcmFnZS1kb3dubG9hZC5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbYInKi5j
b250ZW50LXN0b3JhZ2UtdXBsb2FkLmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tgiAqLmNvbnRlbnQt
c3RvcmFnZS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbYIQKi5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbYIhKi5zdG9y
YWdlLWRvd25sb2FkLmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tgh8qLnN0b3JhZ2UtdXBsb2FkLmdv
b2dsZWFwaXMuY29tgh8qLnN0b3JhZ2Uuc2VsZWN0Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tgiBj
b21tb25kYXRhc3RvcmFnZS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbYIrc3RhdGljLnBhbm9yYW1p
by5jb20uc3RvcmFnZS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbYIWc3RvcmFnZS5nb29nbGVhcGlz
LmNvbYIdc3RvcmFnZS5zZWxlY3QuZ29vZ2xlYXBpcy5jb22CD3VuZmlsdGVyZWQu
bmV3czBoBggrBgEFBQcBAQRcMFowLQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGIWh0dHA6Ly9wa2kuZ29v
Zy9nc3IyL0dUU0dJQUczLmNydDApBggrBgEFBQcwAYYdaHR0cDovL29jc3AucGtp
Lmdvb2cvR1RTR0lBRzMwHQYDVR0OBBYEFIDYGi+iqBDS6hhcK63FsCcyzki1MAwG
A1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUd8K4UJpndnaxLcKG0IOgfqZ+ukswIQYD
VR0gBBowGDAMBgorBgEEAdZ5AgUDMAgGBmeBDAECAjAxBgNVHR8EKjAoMCagJKAi
hiBodHRwOi8vY3JsLnBraS5nb29nL0dUU0dJQUczLmNybDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
AAOCAQEAsNHEdUG4mXtpq1/QwqkL4ljH0HTCi586YHsijMpt6yaVXHxwlofBmB5r
7q/zlPIrIYvwEhl6Hx61mUEvUgnaeSFxYacI6UzRVyD1SA4VACpWCvBSgmNGz4TG
PvN10UvhQr8oje4VTON+UHI1sqLbSMQU6R3hlYQryu8dfl7Rc9evEjErNljATkgU
63DPq2bs/twkmRV/ORwgqzjoIxYK+58mpgV5CJGkdkqhiQAJ2Pu7ZeNdwWuQqjGC
H8kutx7Vvlm84BM4syzRoTWK4pOGmZVbrXHu2yiuHuJyfeT1ZQuNm0yuXW2A4PZh
z+TIiPW8jDr4cXccAslL+BuIpURPWg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with an outdated `sdk_tools/cacerts.txt` file; Google has changed the CA they use, but the code tries to verify against a specific CA trust anchor.

*As an aside, this highlights the difficulties with key pinning.*

The minimum change you can do is to update the CA cert it expects by downloading a [newer version](https://github.com/Kagami/nacl_sdk/blob/master/sdk_tools/cacerts.txt). This still verifies that you're connected to a Google-controlled server.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53538443/934239) by sevenyearslater of ripping this custom check out works too, but makes it possible to spoof the download site in some scenarios.